# OCI error using UniDAC for Delphi

Tags: oracle, delphi

When trying to set up a connexion to an Oracle DB using Delphi XE2, Oracle 11 and UniDAC driver, I get an error :

```
Can't initialize OCI : Error -1
```

I can connect to the server using ODBC.

I'm not using direct connect
   mode.

If I try using direct connect mode, I get another error

```
Unknown host [server name] Socket error code : 11004($2AFC)
```

I'm not
   using TOAD and I don't have any hand on the server itself.

Comment: Which Oracle client do you have installed, 32-bit or 64-bit? And are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for the answers.

I have both version installed and properly registered in the PATH variable.

In fact it's a local configuration file for the build that created the trouble. Everything else was normal.